# Send an image from angular to express sends an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, http-headers

I'm doing this code to send an image file from `angular` to `express` using a **post** **http** request.

```
var req = {
    method:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:3131/api/v0.1/upload',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type   /*"image/jpeg"*/
    },
    data: file
}
```

But when I tried to print the `req.body` it just returns an empty object `{}`.

Comment: try `req.files` instead of `req.body`

Comment: yes, try req.files which should be an array

Comment: @shaishabroy returns `undefined` :(

Comment: @z.a. returns `undefined` :(

Comment: Can you share the code for the file upload handler on the Express server? Also, could you share the code for the file input element?

Comment: yeah a more through code will be helpful.

Comment: I will update the question.